# Custom pcb with 32U4, USB not working

Tags: usb, pcb-design

I am wondering why USB isn't recognised at all.
I followed Sparkfun Pro Micro specs.
Firmware upload works fine (Adrduino Leonardo)
Any help welcome !..

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more detail. What's not recognizing USB? How are you flashing the firmware?

Comment: Did you connect D+ and D- through a 22 Ohm resistor like recommended in the 32U4 datasheet?

Comment: Plug it into a Linux box then run dmesg and edit the last dozen or so lines or anything towards the end mentioning USB into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I followed the Pro Micro specs but I think that the problem is related to the PCB routing which did not take care of USB constraints (differential pair routing).